# Facebook graph api returns no email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm calling

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/?access_token=<valid_token>
```

or just

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=<valid_token>
```

and getting back json object that doesn't contain primary user email which I need.
I setup email permission for the app and no effect.
What can be wrong?

Comment: Did you debug the access token to verify it got the email permission ?

Comment: Check your access token for whether it _really_ contains `email` permission here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: No I didn't. How can I do that?

Comment: Oops didn't notice CBroe's link, check 2 comments up :)

Comment: Oh gosh, it's so simple) Thanks for advice. You may repeat your comment as answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Make sure to try your acess token with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and make sure that the "email" permission on the left is *not greyed out*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you remember to ask for the email permission in the login request? You do this by adding the scope parameter like this in the login request (&scope=email):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING&scope=email
```

[Facebook API reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/#step4)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly I forgot to do

Comment: Andreas, i know it was on 2013, but you rocks!

Answer (score 7):

You probably do not have `email` permissions in your access token.

You can verify it with the [Acess Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: Thanks again, no offence, but I accept Andreas answer as correct cause it was the real reason. But your advice was very helpful in understaning the source of problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your question is, even after granting permission to access email, you are not able to get email information through the Graph API. In newer versions, you need to pass fields param to the API to get additional information such as email. By default, it only provides id and name in response. Please find a sample below on how to get other info from graph :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,first_name,gender,last_name,link,locale,name,timezone,updated_time,verified&access_token=<value of access_token>&debug=all
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the email is not verified in facebook. In this case facebook doesn't make it available via the API. Make sure your code handles this case.

Answer (score 1):

Since the release of API version 2.5 you can get user email like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,email`